# match and delete elements in arraylists

Tags: java, arraylist

I am making a robot maze where the robot reaches a target automatically without crashing into walls. I want the robot to do the maze once, learn the correct route and then the second time be able to get there straight away without going to any deadends. I thought I could do this by making three arraylists.

One for all the squares the robot visits.
Two for all the squares that lead to a deadend.
Three for all the directions the robot goes.

If the squares that lead to a dead end are found in the first arraylist then i can delete the same indexes in the third arraylist. That way, the second time, i can just iterate the third Arraylist.

My full code is below:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Explorer {

    private int pollRun = 0; // Incremented after each pass.
    private RobotData robotData; // Data store for junctions.
    private ArrayList<Integer> nonWallDirections;   
    private ArrayList<Integer> passageDirections; 
    private ArrayList<Integer> beenbeforeDirections;
    private Random random = new Random();
    int [] directions = {IRobot.AHEAD, IRobot.LEFT, IRobot.RIGHT, IRobot.BEHIND};
    private ArrayList<Square> correctSquares;
    private ArrayList<Square> wrongSquares;
    private ArrayList<Integer> correctDirections;

    public void controlRobot (IRobot robot) {

        // On the first move of the first run of a new maze.
        if ((robot.getRuns() == 0) && (pollRun ==0))
            robotData = new RobotData();
        pollRun++; /* Increment poll run so that the data is not reset 
                        each time the robot moves. */


        int exits = nonwallExits(robot);
        int direction;

        if ((robot.getRuns() != 0))
            direction = grandfinale(robot);

        nonWallDirections = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        passageDirections = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        beenbeforeDirections = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        correctSquares = new ArrayList<Square>();
        correctDirections = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            // Adding each direction to the appropriate state ArrayList.
            for(int item : directions) {
                if(robot.look(item) != IRobot.WALL) {
                    nonWallDirections.add(item);
                }
            }

            for(int item : directions) {
                if(robot.look(item) == IRobot.PASSAGE) {
                    passageDirections.add(item);
                }
            }

            for(int item : directions) {
                if(robot.look(item) == IRobot.BEENBEFORE) {
                    beenbeforeDirections.add(item);
                }
            }

        // Calling the appropriate method depending on the number of exits.
        if (exits < 2) {
            direction = deadEnd(robot);
        } else if (exits == 2) {
            direction = corridor(robot);
        } else {
            direction = junction(robot);
            robotData.addJunction(robot);
            robotData.printJunction(robot);
        } 

        robot.face(direction);
        addcorrectSquares(robot);
        correctDirections.add(direction);

    }


    /* The specification advised to have to seperate controls: Explorer and Backtrack
        and a variable explorerMode to switch between them.
        Instead, whenever needed I shall call this backtrack method.
        If at a junction, the robot will head back the junction as to when it first approached it.
        When at a deadend or corridor, it will follow the beenbefore squares until it
        reaches an unexplored path. */
    public int backtrack (IRobot robot) {

        if (nonwallExits(robot) > 2) {
            addwrongSquares(robot);
            return robotData.reverseHeading(robot);
        } else {
                do {
                    addwrongSquares(robot);
                    return nonWallDirections.get(0);
                } while (nonwallExits(robot) == 1);
        }



    }


    //  Deadend method makes the robot follow the only nonwall exit.
    public int deadEnd (IRobot robot) {

        return backtrack(robot);

    }


    /* Corridor method will make the robot follow the one and only passage. 
        The exception is at the start. Sometimes, the robot will start with 
        two passages available to it in which case it will choose one randomly.
        If there is no passage, it will follow the beenbefore squares
        until it reaches an unexplored path.*/
    public int corridor (IRobot robot) {

        if (passageExits(robot) == 1) {
            return passageDirections.get(0);
        } else if (passageExits(robot) == 2) {
            int randomPassage = random.nextInt(passageDirections.size());
            return passageDirections.get(randomPassage);
        } else {
                return backtrack(robot);
        }
    }


    /* Junction method states if there is more than one passage, it will randomly select one.
        This applies to crossroads as well as essentially they are the same.
        If there is no passage, it will follow the beenbefore squares until it reaches an unexplored
        path. */
    public int junction(IRobot robot) {

        if (passageExits(robot) == 1) {
            return passageDirections.get(0);
        } else if (passageExits(robot) > 1) {
            int randomPassage = random.nextInt(passageDirections.size());
            return passageDirections.get(randomPassage);
        } else {
            return backtrack(robot);
        }

    }


    // Calculates number of exits.
    private int nonwallExits (IRobot robot) {

        int nonwallExits = 0;

        for(int item : directions) {
            if(robot.look(item) != IRobot.WALL) {
               nonwallExits++;
            }
        }

        return nonwallExits;
    }


    // Calculates number of passages.
    private int passageExits (IRobot robot) {

        int passageExits = 0;

        for(int item : directions) {
            if(robot.look(item) == IRobot.PASSAGE) {
                passageExits++;
            }
        }

        return passageExits;
    }


    // Calculates number of beenbefores.
    private int beenbeforeExits (IRobot robot) {

        int beenbeforeExits = 0;

        for(int item : directions) {
            if(robot.look(item) == IRobot.PASSAGE) {
                beenbeforeExits++;
            }
        }

        return beenbeforeExits;
    }

    // Resets Junction Counter in RobotData class.
    public int reset() {

        return robotData.resetJunctionCounter();

    }


    public void addcorrectSquares(IRobot robot) {

        Square newSquare = new Square(robot.getLocation().x, robot.getLocation().y);
        correctSquares.add(newSquare);

    }


    public void addwrongSquares(IRobot robot) {

        Square badSquare = new Square(robot.getLocation().x, robot.getLocation().y);
        wrongSquares.add(badSquare);

    }


    public int grandfinale (IRobot robot) {

        IntStream.range(0, correctSquares.size())
            .map(index -> correctSquares.size() - index - 1)
            .filter(index -> (((wrongSquares.x).contains(correctSquares.x)) && ((wrongSquares.y).contains(correctSquares.y))).get(index))
            .forEach(index -> correctDirections.remove(index));

        Iterator<Integer> routeIterator = correctDirections.iterator();
        while (routeIterator.hasNext()) {
            break;
        }

        return (routeIterator.next());
    }
}

class RobotData { 

    /* It was advised in the specification to include the variable:
        private static int maxJunctions = 10000;
        However, as I am not using arrays, but ArrayLists, I do not 
        need this. */
    private static int junctionCounter = 0;
    private ArrayList<Junction> junctionList = new ArrayList<Junction>();

    // Resets the Junction counter.
    public int resetJunctionCounter() {

        return junctionCounter = 0;

    }


    // Adds the current junction to the list of arrays.
    public void addJunction(IRobot robot) {

        Junction newJunction = new Junction(robot.getLocation().x, robot.getLocation().y, robot.getHeading());
        junctionList.add(newJunction);
        junctionCounter++;

    }


    // Gets the junction counter for Junction info method in Junction class.
    public int getJunctionCounter (IRobot robot) {

        return junctionCounter;
    }


    // Prints Junction info.
    public void printJunction(IRobot robot) {

        String course = "";
        switch (robot.getHeading()) {
            case IRobot.NORTH:
                course = "NORTH";
                break;
            case IRobot.EAST:
                course = "EAST";
                break;
            case IRobot.SOUTH:
                course = "SOUTH";
                break;
            case IRobot.WEST:
                course = "WEST";
                break;
        }

        System.out.println("Junction " + junctionCounter + " (x=" + robot.getLocation().x + ", y=" + robot.getLocation().y +") heading " + course);

    }

    /* Iterates through the junction arrayList to find the 
        heading of the robot when it first approached the junction.
        It does this by finding the first junction in the ArrayList 
        that has the same x and y coordinates as the robot.*/
    public int searchJunction(IRobot robot) {

    Junction currentJunction = null;

    Iterator<Junction> junctionIterator = junctionList.iterator();
    while (junctionIterator.hasNext()) {
        currentJunction = junctionIterator.next(); 
        if ((((currentJunction.x)==(robot.getLocation().x))) && ((currentJunction.y)==(robot.getLocation().y))) 
            break;
    }

    return currentJunction.arrived;
}


    // Returns the reverse of the heading the robot had when first approaching the junction.
    public int reverseHeading(IRobot robot) {

        int firstHeading = searchJunction(robot);
        int reverseHeading = 1; // Random integer to Iniitalise variable.

        switch (firstHeading) {
                    case IRobot.NORTH:
                        if (robot.getHeading() == IRobot.NORTH)
                            reverseHeading = IRobot.BEHIND;
                        else if (robot.getHeading() == IRobot.EAST)
                            reverseHeading = IRobot.RIGHT;
                        else if (robot.getHeading() == IRobot.SOUTH)
                            reverseHeading = IRobot.AHEAD;
                        else 
                            reverseHeading = IRobot.LEFT;
                    break;

                    case IRobot.EAST:
                        if (robot.getHeading() == IRobot.NORTH)
                            reverseHeading = IRobot.LEFT;
                        else if (robot.getHeading() == IRobot.EAST)
                            reverseHeading = IRobot.BEHIND;
                        else if (robot.getHeading() == IRobot.SOUTH)
                            reverseHeading = IRobot.RIGHT;
                        else 
                            reverseHeading = IRobot.AHEAD;
                    break;

                    case IRobot.SOUTH:
                        if (robot.getHeading() == IRobot.NORTH)
                            reverseHeading = IRobot.AHEAD;
                        else if (robot.getHeading() == IRobot.EAST)
                            reverseHeading = IRobot.LEFT;
                        else if (robot.getHeading() == IRobot.SOUTH)
                            reverseHeading = IRobot.BEHIND;
                        else 
                            reverseHeading = IRobot.RIGHT;
                    break;

                    case IRobot.WEST:
                        if (robot.getHeading() == IRobot.NORTH)
                            reverseHeading = IRobot.RIGHT;
                        else if (robot.getHeading() == IRobot.EAST)
                            reverseHeading = IRobot.AHEAD;
                        else if (robot.getHeading() == IRobot.SOUTH)
                            reverseHeading = IRobot.LEFT;
                        else 
                            reverseHeading = IRobot.BEHIND;
                    break;
                }

        return reverseHeading;

    }

}


class Junction {

    int x;
    int y;
    int arrived;

    public Junction(int xcoord, int ycoord, int course) {

        x = xcoord;
        y = ycoord;
        arrived = course;

    }

}


class Square {

    int x;
    int y;

    public Square(int cordx, int cordy){

        x = cordx;
        y = cordy;

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you out any thing? Please provide your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
IntStream.range(0, al1.length)
    .filter(index -> al2.contains(al1.get(index)))
    .forEach(index -> al3.remove(index));
```

Slightly more complex than this if removing elements from al3 shifts them left but in that case just reverse the stream before the .filter- then it will delete from the end. The easiest way to do that is:

```
.map(index -> al1.length - index - 1)
```

Without Streams the equivalent would be

```
for (int i = 0; i < al1.length; i++) {
    if (al2.contains(al1.get(i))) {
        al3.remove(i);
    }
}
```

Similarly, if you need to delete from the right then the for loop would need to count down rather than up.

Without further details on arraylist structure it's hard to give any more hints.

Comment: It says it cannot find the symbol for Instream?

Comment: I think he is not using java8

Comment: Sorry it should be IntStream - I've changed it in my answer

Comment: it still cannot find the symbol?

Comment: Ok then you probably aren't using Java 8 as Naman suggests above. You can get exactly the same effect with iteration but more code will be required. I'll edit the answer to give you a hint. Without knowing the structure of your arraylists it's hard to be too specific.

Comment: Thank you! I tried applying it but I couldn't get it to work so i thought I would provide a full explanation.

Comment: Hmmm. I've just realised I'm help you out in a different question on the backtracking algorithm. Honestly I think there's probably quite a lot of stuff you need to do to get this work. I can see an immediate problem is that your Square and Junction classes don't implement equals so contains won't work.